# Parse XML returned data from foreign domain request

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to parse XML data returned from a foreign website. I use a domain request to send some variables to a website like this : http://www.url.com/page.php?var1=val1&var2=val2...

I get this back appended inside a `<div>` :

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<liste>
<produits>
<produit>
<nomprod>Title</nomprod>
<desc>Desc</desc>
<texte>Text</texte>
<url>http://www.url.com</url>
</produit>
</produits>
</liste>
```

I would like to parse these datas and show them in my page correctly

Any help would be very appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by correctly?

Comment: I mean with html tag (id class) for styling it, instead of <title> xml tag I must have something like <div id="title">

Answer (score 0):

[JKL.ParseXML](http://www.kawa.net/works/js/jkl/parsexml-e.html) is a really simple to use library you might want to look at. You can get values from your xml with this super simple code

```
var xml = yourXMlInAString,
    data = xml.parse(),
    title, desc, text, url;
title = data["liste"]["produits"]["produit"]["nomprod"];
desc = data["liste"]["produits"]["produit"]["desc"];
text = data["liste"]["produits"]["produit"]["text"];
url = data["liste"]["produits"]["produit"]["url"];
```

Then you can do what you want with the data, that's of course up to you.

Alternatively, [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) also makes parsing XML, thought I would understand if you opted for the lighter library! If you were to use it, you'd want to look at the [parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) function, there's good documentation on the function's page, so take a look there if you opt for jQuery.

Comment: The problem is that my XML datas are inside my div in my html page (it was appended here) so I don't have a .xml file to point out